# Using microdata on elements created after during page load

Tags: html, web, seo, microdata, rich-snippets

I need to add microdata snippets to a list that is being populated by a script during the page load.

My code is written in a way that I have the basic list element in my html code, and it gets duplicated as the list is populated (this happens once when the page is loaded).

I try to add microdata to every element in the list, but when I use [google's rich snippet tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) it seems that it only reads the basic html snippet and not the whole list after it was populated. I do the exact same trick on a different page and there it seems to work fine (meaning i get a list of videoObjects each containing the data inserted to it) [**edit**: the second page was created on server side, this is why it worked on it].

Any idea how to get around problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, search engines do not read content dynamically created by JavaScript. So anything your script dynamically creates will be invisible to Google. If you want them to index this content you need to create this content server side.

Comment: Most methods of adding content to the DOM via JavaScript are supported. The problem is the original poster is trying to add meta HTML via this method, which doesn't appear to be supported as of yet.